# autocomplete filenames with underscores

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete

What do I need to add to my `~/.bashrc` so that if, for example, there is a file named `name_separated_by_under_score`, I can press <kbd>n</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> and then [TAB] and the shell will auto-complete the file name? (I remember seeing this option)

Comment: Are you sure you saw the option with bash and not another shell? Maybe `fish` or `zsh` or some other more fancy shell?

Comment: almost certainly sure bashrc  (small possibility it was tcsh/csh)  @terdon

Comment: There is an option (namely `completion-map-case`) to treat hyphens `-` and underscores `_` as equivalent when performing case-insensitive completions.  But even then, there is no reason for completion to _stop_ at underscores.

Comment: If you're using a terminal under X11 (GUI), then you can do almost any magic you desire with a tool like AutoKey https://github.com/guoci/autokey-py3 . Not an answer because it won't work at all if you're not using a GUI and it's not the same as auto-complete.

Comment: I think that it was a custom completion script in `.bashrc` rather than an out-of-the-box bash feature, but implementing it thoroughly (taking into account all corner cases and keeping this completion script fast) seems quite complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the Emacs aggressive ["partial completion" completion-style](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Styles.html).

Frequently completion is specified *per-command*. Here we use `complete -D` the default completion (but without any on-demand completion handler loading), bash-4.1 or later is required. This won't work well (or at all) with the bash-completion package or other per-command defined completions, if you have any of those. As is, it also won't complete commands, only arguments.

```
function _bc_magicmatch() {
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]} # the current token ($2 iff bash>=4.3)
  local pat prefix

  ## kick-in condition
  [[ $cur =~ ^(.*/)?([^/]+) ]] && {    # match (path/)(name)

    prefix=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    pat=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    prefix=$(compgen -W "$prefix")     # expand specials, like ~

    ## first form: "-" in input for "_" in expanded names
    pat="${pat//-/*_}*"  # sprinkle "*" in to allow expansion

    ## second form: "-" in input matches [_-] in expanded names
    #pat="${pat//-/*[_-]}*"  # sprinkle "*" in to allow expansion

    ## third form: for no "-" at all in input
    #[[ $pat =~ ${pat//?/(.)} ]]  # split into character array
    #IFS="*" pat="${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1}*" # add IFS separator, skipping index 0

    readarray -t COMPREPLY  < <(compgen -G "${prefix:+$prefix}$pat")
    return
  }
  COMPREPLY=() # revert to completion defaults
}

# bind completion function
complete -D -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _bc_magicmatch
## or selectively, for a subset of commands (works with bash<4.1)
# complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _bc_magicmatch cmd1 cmd2 ...
```

The pattern in the kick-in conditional can limit activation, it can be changed to `.-.-`  i.e. minimum of two hyphenated parts, or `.+-(.+-)+` allows more than one leading character (more like the Emacs behaviour).
You can also modify the `pat` expansion, the alternative second form not enabled above would allow `-` or `_` in the expanded matching names.

If you don't want any separator at all in your input (it's not clear from your example if you want hyphens between the characters), a little extra work is required, use the third form above. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34634535/1955371) on stackoverflow which explains what `//?/(.)/` and `BASH_REMATCH` are being used for.

Note that `compgen -W` expands all words, including `$()` or ``` `` ``` (this only ever executes code you typed into the command prompt, so it's not "dangerous"). `compgen -G` only expands globs, and `~` or `~user` are not glob-able.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf). In addition to being a great standalone tool it supports ["fuzzy" completions](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#fuzzy-completion-for-bash-and-zsh) similar to what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend fish shell. (https://fishshell.com/)

It supports fuzzy matching and a great history search / traversal. Packed with other features as well.

It event supports custom completion functions if needed, although the built in fuzzy searching works great. Read more here: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#tab-completion